# Is it possible to run a Powershell script in the remote computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I wish to run a 'IE Rest Script' to a node present in the same network.

The Script is present in the `MachineA` and it should be executed in the `MachineB` which is present in the same network.

Script:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.visualbasic

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("rundll32")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{tab}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(" ")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("r")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("c")

taskkill.exe /f /im iexplore.exe`
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command`

Comment: You should be googling this question rather than posting directly on SO.

Comment: Please show your research efforts and narrow down your question to a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myremotehost.mydomain.tld -ScriptBlock {
    # This code here runs on the remote system
}
```

You have to make sure, that [PowerShell Remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is activated on the target system.

Comment: Will this code work for the above Script? But on execution of the above script it will Internet Explorer Reset pop up on the running machine (local host) but its not working on the Remote machines.

Comment: If the necessary assemblies are installed/present on the remote system: yes

Comment: Yep the assembly are available on the remote system.  And if the same script work executed on that targeted system its working fine

Comment: Then what is keeping you from just trying it out?

Comment: But when i trigger the same script from the machine A to machine B it is not executing and the IE is not reseted.